# How to Update and Set column value using a sub-string inside a sub-query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

During altering the column size from MAX to 300 characters, I want to update all the values in the column to less than 300 characters, if the `len() > 300`.

```
UPDATE table_name 
SET comments = (SELECT SUBSTRING(comments, 1, 299) 
                FROM table_name 
                WHERE LEN(comments) > 300) 
WHERE LEN(comments ) > 300 
  AND person_id = '1234567890'
```

Any help, would be much appreciated.

Comment: *After altering the field size from MAX to 300 characters* if the alteration succeeded, this means that the column did not have any data longer than 300 chars, so there is nothing to be done.

Comment: yeah, i should have said 'During the alteration', but you are right. Thanks!

Comment: I think *before altering...* is more appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use a subquery at all:

```
UPDATE table_name 
SET comments = SUBSTRING(comments, 1, 299) 
WHERE LEN(comments ) > 300 
  AND person_id = '1234567890'
```

Answer (score 0):

this is needed to be done before alteration. Alteration can be done if the altered column does not have data larger than 300 characters long. Otherwise, SQL server Gives error.

[Check This](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=edb5ac54fc52e75881c9f9c11b33b783)